# Will TrueCrypt affect my ability to restore my Storage Spaces drive pool?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, truecrypt, storage, storage-spaces

I have 2x1TB set up in a two-way mirror with Storage Spaces. I'm going to reformat Windows, do I need to prepare anything to make them show up in the fresh install? Using Windows 8.1 and TrueCrypt 7.1a.

Comment: Are you saying you are going to format these drives, setup Storage Spaces, then encrypt the volume?  You might consider making that more clear by editing your question.  I can tell you that Storage Spaces and Truecrypt WILL NOT work well together.

Comment: @Ramhound my bad. I meant the OS.

Comment: @Ramhound Why is that? I have them going on two machines and so far it's been fine. I read that SS works a level below encryption so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you already have this *Mirror Space* setup?

Comment: If you already have it working, then it clearly isn't a problem, my research said otherwise.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, that's what I was worried about. Seems kind of pointless though if it's unique to each installation.

Comment: I personally don't trust Storage Spaces for varitey of reasons.  But it can be moved, it was the next thing I looked up, which is the reason I won't submit an answer.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, `Storage Spaces` is a software RAID. You need Windows already running to have it working and create a unique drive letter.

You need either hardware RAID or a more complicated setup (or a smarter encryption software) : I'm not sure this is possible this way with Windows and `Truecrypt`.

That said, `Truecrypt` is obsolete ([source](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/)):

> WARNING: Using TrueCrypt is not secure as it may contain unfixed security issues
>
> This page exists only to help migrate existing data encrypted by TrueCrypt.
>
> The development of TrueCrypt was ended in 5/2014 after Microsoft terminated support of Windows XP. Windows 8/7/Vista and later offer integrated support for encrypted disks and virtual disk images. Such integrated support is also available on other platforms (click here for more information). You should migrate any data encrypted by TrueCrypt to encrypted disks or virtual disk images supported on your platform.

So you should consider using something else like `bitlocker` which allows you to do just that.

---

**Edit:**

Sorry, I didn't understand that these disks were not containing Windows... Then you just have to re-install `Truecrypt` and re-declare the setup with `Space Storages`. You should be able to read them as you used to. However my comment on `Truecrypt` is still true. :)

---

**Edit2:**

As an alternative (and safer way to do it), you can remove one of the disks of the pool, format it, copy files from disk 1 to disk 2, reinstall Windows, and setup the RAID again with SS + TC (or `bitlocker`).

Comment: Truecrypt is not obsolete. A recently completed full audit of it's code shows it has no major issues.

Comment: Last TC update was more than a year ago with the above warning from its author himself. There might be no usable exploits right now, but it will and then you would have to start everything again (or continue using it without knowing).

Comment: BTW, the audit, which was performed by only 3 people showed that there have been at least 4 vulnerabilities in that last version (or are you considering those are "no major issues"?). May I also remind you the OpenSSL saga to keep a more conservative judgment?

Comment: And nobody ever provided any factual information to back up that warning. https://www.grc.com/misc/truecrypt/truecrypt.htm

Comment: http://www.ghacks.net/2015/04/02/truecrypt-audit-phase-ii-completed-4-vulnerabilities-identified/

Comment: Not that there is no workaround. But again, an unmaintained crypto software is broken and should not be used.

Comment: I'd rather use unmaintained crypto software which has been concisely audited than maintained crypto software which is closed-source, functions in an unknown manner, and it's code and maintenance policies are not revealed to the public.

Comment: Come on. Unmaintained IS broken for this kind of software. I would not advise to move on to something else for an **existing** volume (no critical vulnerability found yet), but for a **new** one, this is just silly. I think I missed something: you don't trust `bitlocker` but you do trust Windows??? Why providing a backdoor when you can send requested files directly by the OS after decryption by the user? So you don't trust MS' `bitlocker` but you trust MS' OS? Nevermind, then use LUKS: it's built in all nix/bsd and can be used in Windows too (https://github.com/t-d-k/LibreCrypt).

Comment: Unmaintained does not mean broken. Nor did I mention anything about trust, bitlocker, LUKS, or Windows at any point.

Comment: Factually, it does: every software is subject to bitrot once unmaintained AND as far as crypto software are concerned, again factually, new attack vectors are found. The TC audit unvailed 4 of them including 2 high impact ones. This list will grow bigger with time. You didn't explicitely mention trust but that's what it is when you say you'd rather use unmaintained but audited crypto rather than a closed-source undocumented software.

Comment: Factually, it does not. By your logic, all wireless encryption is broken, most ATMs are broken, secure boot is broken and self-encrypting disks are all broken. You seem to have very little understanding of software or security and clearly haven't read the audit or link I posted earlier ("No significant cryptographic problems found"). Of the two "high impact" attack vectors you refer, one is shared by Bitlocker and the other requires you have a 5+ year old computer and an attacker with admin rights on your machine, and both can be completely and 100% mitigated with two mouse clicks.

Comment: I'm curious to know why all wireless encryption is broken or why most ATM are broken though. Most problems with crypto code comes from its implementation: the underlying crypto is rarely broken by itself but implementations are. But whatever, I really don't want to fight over such a small matter (for me anyway). Since you imply that I don't understand anything in the matter, I'll just state again that the **TC author** not only said that his software could not be trusted anymore but also performed a last release in which you cannot create new TC volumes. This seems crystal clear to me.